# Office reference in TFS Build Server

Tags: .net, outlook, office-interop, tfs-2015

I have win-from project where it uses `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`

When I run the build from TFS it fails with below error message

***"Error BC30652: Reference required to assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' containing the type 'COMAddIns'"***

I have tried installing Redistributable Primary Interop Assemblies to build server which didnt help.

Also tried adding "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll" to a project folder and referring it from there. But still no luck

Can someone please point me to right direction

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a reference to Outlook from the COM tab of the References dialog n in VS (whcih will regenerate the interop dll on each rebuild), add a reference to an interop dll generated previously or using the TlbImp.exe utility.